# Is there a general expression for this pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

I am trying to find a general expression for this pattern, I know it must be something stupidly easy but I can't seem to find it. Could somebody please help me?

[image: This is the pattern I have so far]

Comment: In words, the conjecture is "the sum of I's indexed by odd integers up to n equals the sum of I's indexed by even integers up to n."

Comment: The "pattern" seems to be $$I_1-(-1)^nI_n=\sum_{k=2}^n(-1)^kI_k$$

Comment: I meant  $$I_1- (-1)^nI_n=\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(-1)^kI_k.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sum of $(-1)^iI_i$ for $i = 2$ to $n-1$

Answer (score 0):

For $n$ even, let $k=n/2$, then if you put the even terms on the left and odds on the right, it is $$\sum_{i=1}^kI _{2i}=\sum_{i=1}^kI _{2i-1}$$ For $n$ odd, increase the upper limit on the right by $1$.